# What other blockchains support the EVM execution model?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, evm

In essence I'm interested in which other chains (mostly Layer 1) I can deploy Solidity smart contracts to?

I know of TRON. And I also know Cosmos, Polkadot and NEAR have at least some support. But does anybody know more details here and/or other blockchains with EVM support? I think Cardano also has planned EVM support for the future.

Comment: I think you can also use EVM on Rootstock, the smart contract platform for Bitcoin.